# Django many-to-many relationship with extra fields

Tags: django, many-to-many

I am building a simple interface to a biological database using the django-admin to populate the db. I want tot to use a many-to-many relationship for a questionnaire to fish species (one questionnaire can have more than one species and one species can be present in more than one questionnaire). The two models in question:

```
class Species(models.Model):
    fish_spp_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)


class Questionaire(models.Model):
    # ...
    fish_caught = models.ManyToManyField(Species)
```

now, I want to my data to contain a number of each species caught, per questionnaire. So, for example, I can associate 3 different species with questionnaire id=1, but how do I include that, say 2 of the first species, 1 of the second and 4 of the third were caught?

Comment: Perhaps you need an "association" or "though" table like this design: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2156950/query-for-a-manytomany-field-with-through-in-django

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Define another models `Caught` to hold the information per catch.  Give it a `related_name` to make it easier to refer to in your code.  You might also want to `unique_together` appropriate fields.

```
class Species(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s/%d' % self.name

class Questionaire(models.Model):
    pass

class Caught(models.Model):
    species = models.ForeignKey(Species)
    number = models.IntegerField()
    questionaire = models.ForeignKey(
        Questionaire, related_name='catches')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s/%d' % (self.species.name, self.number)
```

Use it like this:

```
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from app.models import *
>>> s1 = Species(name='Salmon')
>>> s1.save()
>>> s2 = Species(name='Mackerel')
>>> s2.save()
>>> q = Questionaire()
>>> q.save()
>>> c1 = Caught(species=s1, number=7, questionaire=q)
>>> c2 = Caught(species=s2, number=5, questionaire=q)
>>> c1.save()
>>> c2.save()
>>> q.catches.all()
[<Caught: Salmon/7>, <Caught: Mackerel/5>]
>>>
```

Comment: Ok, so in fact I simply define my models using foreign keys instead of many-to-many? This is fine, though I end up with two form for the data entry (Questionnaire and then Fish Caught). Before, I got as far as using the many-to-many from Questionnaire to Species, which produced a handy multiple-select for fish species. I just wondered if it was at all possible to extend this within the questionnaire form so that all of that data could be recorded in the one form (i.e. select species which produces another  form for caught number entry? Either way your way definitely works.

Comment: Ok, got it. If I specify an inline class for the Caught model.Admin, and reference it as an inline in the Questionnaire model.Admin, I get exactly the behavior I was looking for :)

Comment: This answer is no longer valid since Django supports Many-To-Many objects 'out of the box'. OP consider changing the accepted answer.

Answer (score 8):

Check this:  **[Extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#intermediary-manytomany)**